# How do I subscribe to a postcast by its URL iPhone Podcasts app?

Tags: ios, podcasts

I have a podcast RSS URL (copied in the clipboard) that I want to listen to in the Apple Podcasts app. On the "Listen Now" screen there's a link for "Add a show by URL" but when I tap it, nothing happens. I can't see another option to add a Podcast URL.

Brand new iPhone 12 on iOS on iOS 15.1.

Comment: You are performing the right steps. Please update your phone to the latest iOS version and try again, since sometimes older versions have bugs that have been fixed.

Comment: Thanks, I think this was a bug. After an upgrade it worked. Disappointing that there would be such a bug out of the box. I'll leave the question here though, I think someone else might run in to it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this was a bug in the Podcasts app. An upgrade to iOS 15.4 fixed it.